# axiomatizability proof using compactness

Tags: logic

We say that a property P is axiomatizable if there is a theory T such that, if A is a structure, then: $A \models T \iff A$ has the property $P$. We say that P is finitely axiomatizable if there is a sentence E such that $A \models E \iff A$ has the property $P$.
I need to prove that if P is axiomatizable by a theory T, and if we suppose that P is finitely axiomatizable, then P is axiomatizable by $T_0 \subseteq T$.
I thought that, by the two hypothesis of the statement, we could say that $E = \bigwedge\limits_{t \in T} t$ axiomatizes $P$. By definition of $E$, it follows that $T \models E$ and therefore, by Compactness theorem, $\exists T_0 \subseteq T$ s.t. $T_0 \models E$. How do I conclude the proof? I know that $A \models T_0$ since it is a subset of $T$, but I don't know how it may help.

Comment: The statement is trivial because you can take $T_0=T.$ Did you mean to say a **finite** $T_0\subseteq T$?

Comment: It doesn't specify it, but I assume it was meant to be finite.